# Trouble reading numbers from file into array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

There are 26 numbers in the `numbers.txt` file. Those 26 numbers are supposed to be read to `arr` but instead I get 26 zeroes in my array.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
int n = 0;
int i = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    scanner.next();
    n++;
} // n is now 26 
int[] arr = new int[n];
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zeroes are default value for array. a scanner is "single-use", it's single-pass. you used it once, you have to create another (maybe by earlier having the `File` object in a variable and then using it to create both `Scanner`s?) or somehow reverse its state. the second loop has zero iterations, it never `hasNextInt` anymore

Answer (score 0):

Michał is right -- you need to repeat the `scanner = new Scanner(...)` after your `// n is now 26` line.

Or, better, use an `ArrayList<Integer>()` rather than `int[]`, then you only need a single pass:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.print(numbers);
}
```